# VBA SQL 'No value given for one or more required parameters' but field exists

Tags: sql, excel, vba, oledb

I am trying to run sql queries on one spreadsheet from another in Excel 2010 VBA.

My connection is set up properly and works as expected, except for 1 column, which for some reason is giving me this error. I checked the name of the column and I also tried renaming it to something super simple, but it still still doesn't. Can anyone think of what else the issue might be. All other columns work for selecting.

> ```
> strConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & workbookPath _
>                             & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";"
> ```

This is the query, it works for all other fields except the "Ticker Number" column. I tried renaming it in the source file but no luck...

> sqlString = "SELECT [Ticket Number] FROM [Sheet1$A1:Z100]"

Comment: Can you provide the entire code block not just line snippets? Whether ADO or DAO is used and how recordsets are defined matters.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this one:

```
strConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0" _
              & ";Data Source=" & workbookPath _
              & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";"
```

Comment: hmm using that string now gives me "Could not find installable ISAM"

Comment: Which version of Excel do you have?

Comment: Excel 2010 on windows 7

Comment: Thatnks, the connection string works but i still have the same problem.

Comment: I tried the same query and it worked. I'm on win8 excel 2010.

Comment: I found the problem. Since the workbook is xlsx, i need to fully qualify it with a "." in the path. I saved the file to .XLS and now i can refer to the workbook without the . and it works.....

Comment: Also make sure that Sheet1 is the correct sheet. The Sheet.Name can be different from the Sheet.CodeName and the driver tries the codename first.